# Header ImageView in Navigation Drawer - Android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, header

I have created a Navigation Drawer and then I want to put an image header without having it to be part of the item resources. I have created a header image but it was clickable and the id of it was the id of the first item. And the header image become a big header in my whole app which can be seen in every page. How can I fix this.

This is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// Boolean keepPlaying = true;
//  MediaPlayer mp;
Item btnplay;
 MediaPlayer mp;
 private boolean isPaused=false; 
 private int length;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            isPlaying = false;
            isPaused = false;
        }
    });
    play(null);//you are calling play by launching


    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array

    // Search
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));     
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // History
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Linux Distro
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    // Dos Vs Linux
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // Linux Commands
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
    // Bash Commands
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
    // Terminal
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));
    // About US
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[8], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(8, -1)));
    // Help
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[9], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(9, -1)));


    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
  //Header of the listview, go to header.xml to customize
    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_navi, null);
  //addHeaderView is to add custom content into first row
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer_invisible, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

//inflate items in actionbar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//Background sounds
boolean isPlaying = false;
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.btnplay) //whatever you named in xml
        {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

public void play(MenuItem menuItem) {

    if (!isPlaying && !isPaused) {
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
      /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "play started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                */
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("bgmusic_mainactivity.ogg");
            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(),
                    afd.getLength());
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();// play sound
            mp.setLooping(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        isPlaying = true;
    } else if (isPlaying) {
       /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "play paused",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                */

        mp.pause();
        isPlaying = false;
        isPaused = true;
        length = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);

        // and for resuming the player from the position where it stopped
        // lately is done by:

    } else if (isPaused) {

        mp.seekTo(length);
        mp.start();
        isPlaying = true;
        isPaused = false;

        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on);
    }

}

/***
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if(isPlaying){
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_on);
    }
    else{
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_volume_muted);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}


/**
 * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        fragment = new CommandList();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new Home();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new History();
        break;    
    case 3:
        fragment = new LinuxDistro();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new DosLinux();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new LinuxCommands();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new BashCommands();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new Terminal();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new AboutUs();
        break;
    case 9:
        fragment = new Help();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment!");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}  

// exit dialog
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you really want to close the app?")
           .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
           .setTitle("Tux To Go Alert!")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    mp.stop();
                    finish();

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
}
```

header_navi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    >
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />


<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"

    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
 android:background="@color/list_background"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is A simple way to add a image or Header in the Navigation :
you can add any View or image view in the "DrawerLayout" just put your list-view in a "LinearLayout"  and add a Image view and the list view in that Layout. It will show the Image View or any other view which you added in the "DrawerLayout" .
As Example :

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        >
    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/header" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"

        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
     android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this code. But it gave me an error. It says, `android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams`

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `<ListView>` and `<ImageView>` in a `<RelativeLayout>` and add this to `<ListView>`

```
android:layout_below="your image id"
```

Replace your image id with image id.